# Matlab - Plot difference between two graphs in specific points

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two graphs, one is the exact graph of a solution, the other is a numerical approach. I have 4 specific points in my figure (t=0.25,0.5,0.75,1), where I want to illustrate the difference between the two graphs with a straight line. I found the errorbars function but i don't see any use there. Hope you can help me!

Edit:

this is the example figure:

```
t = [0:0.25:1]; 
y = t.*4; 
x = t.^2+3; 
plot(t,y,t,x)
```

I have 4 points now, t=0.25; t=0.5; t=0.75; t=1; At this points, I just want a vertical line between the two plots. I already have tried this: `plot([t(1),y(1)],[t(1),x(1)])`

but it just creates a line over the whole figure.

Comment: You know the points between which you want to draw a line then you can simply use `plot`.

Comment: but with plot I get a line over the whole figure, I want it just between the lines

Comment: Then  [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which explains what you have tried and how it is incorrect/not working!

Comment: this is the example figure:
't = [0:0.25:1]; 
y = t.*4;
x = t.^2+3;
plot(t,y,t,x)
'

I have 4 points now,  t=0.25; t=0.5; t=0.75; t=1;
At this points, I just want a vertical line between the two plots.

I already have tried this:
'plot([t(1),y(1)],[t(1),x(1)])'
but it just creates a line over the whole figure.

Comment: Edit you original post please, that way people will not have to search the comments. Also add what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

**✶** It seems that you're not using [**`hold on`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) before using [**`plot`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) command the second time because otherwise you'd have got the desired result (which is actually not a correct way of plotting a vertical line).

**✶** You're mixing up the values of `x` and `y` for **`plot(x,y)`**. To plot a vertical line, it should be used like this: **`plot([x,x], [y1,y2])`**

 For your case, you may not notice the difference between `plot([t(1),y(1)],[t(1),x(1)])` (which is incorrect) and  `plot([t(1),t(1)],[x(1),y(1)])` (which is correct) because it is by chance that the values are same. Plot it for some other points and you'll realize the difference.

**Fixed Code:**

```
t = [0:0.25:1]; 
y = t.*4; 
x = t.^2+3; 
plot(t,y,t,x) 
hold on
plot([t(1) t(1)],[x(1) y(1)])  
% You have 't' on your horizontal axis and 'x'and 'y' values on the vertical axis
axis equal     % just for better visualization
```

**Output:**

[image: output]